# DbContext.Entry() vs DbConext.Attach() for new or not yet tracked object

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using VS 2019 with ASP.NET Core 3.1 and EF Core 3.1, and noticed that the default scaffolded codes for a basic Edit operation is:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
   //...
  _context.Attach(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
   //...
}
```

From the EF tutorials I also learned:

`_context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;`

Looking up the documentation, I understood that `DbContext.Attach` by default sets `Unchanged` state. But would setting the State to `EntityState.Modified` immediately after as shown in the VS scaffolded code be equivalent to setting it via `DbContext.Entry().State`?

Then I wondered if `DbContext.Attach` was used because the entity was not yet being tracked. But MS documentation says this about the `DbContext.Entry()` method:

> This method **may be called on an entity that is not tracked**. You can then set the State property on the returned entry to have the context begin tracking the entity in the specified state.

So this got me a little confused.  Since both `.Entry()` and `.Attach()` (without setting .State yet) returns `EntityEntry<TEntity>`, what is the difference between these two methods, prior to setting the .State property? Can they be used interchangeably in the scenario above?

Comment: I think their biggest difference is State,attach will change state to unchanged,with entry the state is detached.